# Does there exist a language O such that $NL^O= Dtime(n^{logn})^O$? How to proceed with the proof in either case?

Tags: complexity-theory

I do have some intuition(although I would like to be corrected) regarding why $NL!=Dtime(n^{log n})$ as for some $L \in Dtime(n^{log n})$ it might be required for the TM deciding it to read inputs of size $O(n^{log n})$ which isn't possible in logarithmic space constraints. Having an oracle access surely saves a lot of time, but how does it help with space constraints? We're still bounded by logarithmic space. Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, see that we can prove two things as follows:

- The Time hierarchy theorem relativizes. That is, one can prove that even with any oracle $O$, the following holds when $f(n) \log n = o(g(n))$:
  $$ DTime (f(n))^O \subsetneq DTime(g(n))^O $$
- The proof that $$ NL \subseteq P $$ also relativizes. So:
  $$ NL^O \subseteq P^O $$
  for any oracle $O$. The reason is that the TM for any language in $NL$, with oracle $O$, can be converted to a polynomial time, by the similar construction used for proof without oracle, and oracle query is replaced as it is.

Using these two one can just conclude that $NL^O \subsetneq DTime(n\log n)^O$

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion $\mathsf{NL\subseteq P}$ relativizes (remains true relatively to any oracle), from here you can apply the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Yaa, Time Hierarchy Theorem does prove containment in one direction as $Dtime(n^{c} )\subseteq Dtime(n^{log n})$, but I just want to confirm whether proving the reverse direction is possible at all i.e. $Dtime(N^{log n})^{O} \subseteq {NL}^O$ as for proving equality we need to show both the directions to be true. I don't think it's possible in the reverse direction for the same intuition as mentioned above. But as I am new to theory, I would like to validate my beliefs.